# Sending keys in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Winform c# selenium webdriver firefox. It gave me error on this section of the code

```
builder.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.F4);
```

Error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
Additional information: key must be a modifier key (Keys.Shift, Keys.Control, or Keys.Alt)

Code

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Alt);
builder.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control);
builder.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.F4);
builder.KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Alt);
builder.KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.F4);
builder.KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should use `SendKeys` like this:

```
builder.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Alt);
builder.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control);
builder.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.F4);
```

Answer (score 3):

The code in the end should look like this.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.KeyDown(Keys.Alt);
builder.KeyDown(Keys.Control);
builder.SendKeys(Keys.F4);
builder.KeyUp(Keys.Alt);
builder.KeyUp(Keys.F4);
```

I'm not sure what this last line is being used for.

```
builder.KeyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();
```